# How to get email attachments for classic users to come from Files rather than Classic Documents

Tags: email, files, document

When a user in the Salesforce Classic interface creates and email and wants to attach a file, Attachments from Classic users come from (Classic) Documents, Attachments from Lightning users come from Files -